# Loop through each row for each unique user in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, increment

I have a dataframe from a survey in which users were asked questions across multiple days.
I need to create a column which contains an integer equal to what number survey it is for each user.
Something like this:

```
User Survey_Number
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
2    1
2    2
3    1
3    2
3    3
4    1
4    2
5    1
```

How do I increment through each row for each user to assign the value for Survey_Number?
This is what I have, though I know it's probably not on the right track. It sets Survery_Number equal to 0 in each row. (Yes, I know I'm bad at this)

```
for(i in(data.dat$User))
  k<-0
  for(j in (data.dat$Survey_Number))
    data.dat$Survery_Number<-k
    k<-(k+1)
```

Comment: It'd be easier for you to find help if you showed us what `data.dat` looks like. Can you share it by pasting the output of `dput(head(data.dat))` in your question? If not, can you create a dummy dataset? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: (1) You could use `dplyr`: `data.dat %>% group_by(User) %>% mutate(Survey_Number = row_number())`.

Comment: In base: `data.dat$Survey_Number <- unlist(tapply(data.dat$User, data.dat$User, seq_along))`